Stress-testing Laravel API endpoints using PEST
I am trying to implement a stress test suite for Laravel using PHP pest and their stressless plugin.
However, neither in their documentation nor in their code (checked vendor/pestphp/pest-plugin-stressless/src/Factory.php) could I find a way to authenticate a user against API endpoints.
I believe they are using headless browser which does not accept any custom headers.
Is there a workaround for that?
